# this.appendChild(a) - Unexpected call to method or property access

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, runtime, infinite-scroll

I have a run time error on IE8 and IE7 and IE6 it is stating the error is in jQuery.min.js on line 31852

Here is the code i have written so i believe the issue is with the infinite scroll plugin as it appends items to the document.

After some further debugging it seems that the line in question is this:

```
this.appendChild(a)
```

From jQuery.min.js, ie is choking on this line according to the debugger tool.

```
var $container = $('.section');

    function getInternetExplorerVersion()
    {
      var rv = -1; // Return value assumes failure.
      if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer')
      {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re  = new RegExp("MSIE ([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null)
          rv = parseFloat( RegExp.$1 );
      }
      return rv;
    }

      var ver = getInternetExplorerVersion();

      if ( ver > -1 )
      {
        $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.section .article',
            isFitWidth: true,
            columnWidth: 270
          });
      } else {
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector: '.section .article',
            isFitWidth: true,
            columnWidth: 270
          });
        });
      }

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '.footer .nav ul',
      nextSelector : '.footer .nav ul li.next a',
      itemSelector : '.section .article',
      loadingImg   : "images/loader.gif", 
        loadingText  : 'Loading more wishes, please wait...',
        donetext     : "All Wishes have been loaded."
      },
      function( newElements ) {
        var $newElems = $( newElements ).css({ opacity: 0 });
        $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
          $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
          $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true ); 
        });
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using ulightbox plugin?

In my case, I was using ulightbox, so, try deleting some plugins.